# can you figure out how five plus nine equals six?

Tags: calculation-puzzle

Quick riddle here for you **5 + 9 = 6**... how?

I look forward to hearing your answers, and I am writing this part in the hope it allows me to submit. *(it did!)*

Comment: Where did you get this puzzle from? Or did you make it yourself?

Comment: Modulo arithmetric: if you count five points around a eight-pointed compass rose, then nine, you wind up on the sixth point. But nine is more than a full circle...

Answer (score 12):

I suppose if you use Roman numerals to write the 9, and interpret the **+** to mean concatenation, you would have something like

> 5IX

which looks a lot like

> SIX

Answer (score 7):

Consider 5 and 9 as

> seven-segment displays (using overhangs, of course).

If one uses this

> truth table: 0, 0 -> 1; 0, 1 -> 0; 1, 1 -> 1 (1, 0 can be either),

5+9 does indeed equal 6. Note, however, that this can be the rot13(KABE bcrengbe), which is just rot13(gur vairefr bs ovanel nqqvgvba zbq 2)!

Comment: Your truth-table fits xnor

Comment: Yep. I just put it in rot13 because spoiler boxes are annoying.

Answer (score 4):

If 5 is:

> The number of children

and if 9 is:

> The number of months of pregnancy successfully completed, leading to a birth

then 6 is:

> The number of children resulting